# Definition of `integer index` in JavaScript (ECMAScript 2015)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer

I'm trying to understand how a JavaSript object sorts its properties. As far as I understood, from [ECMA262](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), the first properties are always an [integer index](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-object-type) properties. For example, if print these objects using Node.js, Deno, or Bun:

```js
console.log({ a: 0, [-1]: 1 })
console.log({ a: 0, [0]: 1 })
console.log({ a: 0, [2 ** 32 - 2]: 1 })
console.log({ a: 0, [2 ** 32 - 1]: 1 })
console.log({ a: 0, [2 ** 32]: 1 })
```

we will have

```
{ a: 0, '-1': 1 }
{ '0': 1, a: 0 }
{ '4294967294': 1, a: 0 }
{ a: 0, '4294967295': 1 }
{ a: 0, '4294967296': 1 }
```

It looks like an integer index is defined in the range `[0, 2^32-2]`. It matches the definition of an `array index`:

> An *array index* is an integer index whose numeric value *i* is in the range +0 ≤ *i* < 2^32 - 1.

However, it's different from the definition of an `integer index`:

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2^53−1.

So, my question is, should JavaScript engines use `[0, 2^53-1]` or ECMAScript 2015 should use `[0, 2^32-2]` for the definition of an *integer index*? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This algorithm [was changed in 2018 to align with implementation reality](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/pull/1242) to put only *array* indices first, not *integer* indices.

No, engines implementing ES2015 should not redefine integer indices to mean something else than the spec says. They should have used 2<sup>53</sup>-1 (but didn't, at the time). On the other hand, engines implementing [ES2019](https://262.ecma-international.org/10.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) do and should use array indices (up to 2<sup>32</sup>-2) in the *OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys* algorithm, and that's what you are seeing when trying this out.